# SwiftUI App shows NFC card on screen but doesnt read tag

Tags: swiftui, nfc, core-nfc

I'm working on an app that reads an NFC tag and uses that data to select a `Core Data` item. Everything about my app works, except when I press the button to read or write an NFC tag while testing on device, the `NFC Read Card` shows, but the tag won't be read. Occasionally, maybe 1 in 50 attempts, everything works fine and the tag will read, I get haptic feedback, and the card dismisses. I have confirmed with a 3rd party app that my device and the tags are compatible.

The project is [here](https://github.com/jhbetts/Bagchecknfc.git) on Github. I will copy what I believe to be all relevant code here. I would create a minimum viable product, but I don't know what specifically is acting up.

**This handles the NFC logic. It is copied from [SwiftNFC](https://github.com/1998code/SwiftNFC.git). I wasn't able to get it to work when importing as a package.**

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreNFC

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
public class NFCReader: NSObject, ObservableObject, NFCNDEFReaderSessionDelegate {
    
    public var startAlert = "Hold your iPhone near the tag."
    public var endAlert = ""
    public var msg = "Scan to read or Edit here to write..."
    public var raw = "Raw Data available after scan."

    public var session: NFCNDEFReaderSession?
    
    public func read() {
        guard NFCNDEFReaderSession.readingAvailable else {
            print("Error")
            return
        }
        session = NFCNDEFReaderSession(delegate: self, queue: nil, invalidateAfterFirstRead: true)
        session?.alertMessage = self.startAlert
        session?.begin()
    }
    
    public func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didDetectNDEFs messages: [NFCNDEFMessage]) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.msg = messages.map {
                $0.records.map {
                    String(decoding: $0.payload, as: UTF8.self)
                }.joined(separator: "\n")
            }.joined(separator: " ")
            
            self.raw = messages.map {
                $0.records.map {
                    "\($0.typeNameFormat) \(String(decoding:$0.type, as: UTF8.self)) \(String(decoding:$0.identifier, as: UTF8.self)) \(String(decoding: $0.payload, as: UTF8.self))"
                }.joined(separator: "\n")
            }.joined(separator: " ")


            session.alertMessage = self.endAlert != "" ? self.endAlert : "Club Scanned!"
        }
    }
    
    public func readerSessionDidBecomeActive(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession) {
    }
    
    public func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didInvalidateWithError error: Error) {
        print("Session did invalidate with error: \(error)")
        self.session = nil
    }
}

public class NFCWriter: NSObject, ObservableObject, NFCNDEFReaderSessionDelegate {
    
    public var startAlert = "Hold your iPhone near the tag."
    public var endAlert = ""
    public var msg = ""
    public var type = "T"
    
    public var session: NFCNDEFReaderSession?
    
    public func write() {
        guard NFCNDEFReaderSession.readingAvailable else {
            print("Error")
            return
        }
        session = NFCNDEFReaderSession(delegate: self, queue: nil, invalidateAfterFirstRead: true)
        session?.alertMessage = self.startAlert
        session?.begin()
    }
    
    public func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didDetectNDEFs messages: [NFCNDEFMessage]) {
    }

    public func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didDetect tags: [NFCNDEFTag]) {
        if tags.count > 1 {
            let retryInterval = DispatchTimeInterval.milliseconds(500)
            session.alertMessage = "Detected more than 1 tag. Please try again."
            DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + retryInterval, execute: {
                session.restartPolling()
            })
            return
        }
        
        let tag = tags.first!
        session.connect(to: tag, completionHandler: { (error: Error?) in
            if nil != error {
                session.alertMessage = "Unable to connect to tag."
                session.invalidate()
                return
            }
            
            tag.queryNDEFStatus(completionHandler: { (ndefStatus: NFCNDEFStatus, capacity: Int, error: Error?) in
                guard error == nil else {
                    session.alertMessage = "Unable to query the status of tag."
                    session.invalidate()
                    return
                }

                switch ndefStatus {
                case .notSupported:
                    session.alertMessage = "Tag is not NDEF compliant."
                    session.invalidate()
                case .readOnly:
                    session.alertMessage = "Read only tag detected."
                    session.invalidate()
                case .readWrite:
                    let payload: NFCNDEFPayload?
                    if self.type == "T" {
                        payload = NFCNDEFPayload.init(
                            format: .nfcWellKnown,
                            type: Data("\(self.type)".utf8),
                            identifier: Data(),
                            payload: Data("\(self.msg)".utf8)
                        )
                    } else {
                        payload = NFCNDEFPayload.wellKnownTypeURIPayload(string: "\(self.msg)")
                    }
                    let message = NFCNDEFMessage(records: [payload].compactMap({ $0 }))
                    tag.writeNDEF(message, completionHandler: { (error: Error?) in
                        if nil != error {
                            session.alertMessage = "Write to tag fail: \(error!)"
                        } else {
                            session.alertMessage = self.endAlert != "" ? self.endAlert : "Write \(self.msg) to tag successful."
                        }
                        session.invalidate()
                    })
                @unknown default:
                    session.alertMessage = "Unknown tag status."
                    session.invalidate()
                }
            })
        })
    }
    
    public func readerSessionDidBecomeActive(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession) {
    }

    public func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didInvalidateWithError error: Error) {
        print("Session did invalidate with error: \(error)")
        self.session = nil
    }
}
```

**Here is the `View`. I'll remove what I can here for readability, but it wont wont run now. Pull the file from github to run in Xcode.**

```
import SwiftUI
//import SwiftNFC
import CoreNFC

struct ClubListView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var storefront: Storefront
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @EnvironmentObject var locationManager: LocationManagerModel
    @FetchRequest(
        entity: Club.entity(),
        sortDescriptors:[])
    private var clubs:FetchedResults<Club>
    @ObservedObject var NFCR = NFCReader()
    @ObservedObject var NFCW = NFCWriter()
    @State private var shotClub = Club()
    @State private var ballClub = Club()
    @State private var showNewClub: Bool = false
    @State private var showSettings: Bool = false
    @State var premium = false
    @Binding var refreshGames: UUID
    @Binding var refreshClubs: UUID 
    @Binding var counter: Int
    @Binding var puttCounter: Int
    @Binding var roundStarted: Bool
    //@Binding var waiting: Bool
    //@Binding var showError: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ZStack {
                HStack{
                    Spacer()
                    VStack{
                        Spacer()
                        if premium {
                            Button(action: {
                                read()
                                ////READ NFC TAG
                            }, label: {
                                ReadNFCButton()
                                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                            })
                            .padding(.bottom, 30)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 30)
                            .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.3), radius: 3, x: -3.0, y: 0.0)
                            }
                        }
                        
                }
                .zIndex(1.0)
            } //: ZStack
        }.onChange(of: NFCR.msg) {newValue in
            print("test")
            if !locationManager.waiting && !shotClub.putter{
                locationManager.currentLocation(mode: .shot)
                shotClub.name = NFCR.msg
            } else if locationManager.waiting && shotClub.putter {
                locationManager.currentLocation(mode: .ball)
                    ballClub = shotClub
                    if roundStarted {
                        puttCounter += 1
                        counter += 1
                    }
                    
                    shotClub.strokesList.append(0)
                    if ballClub.putter == true {
                        locationManager.waiting = false
                    }
            } else if !locationManager.waiting && shotClub.putter {
                if roundStarted{
                    counter += 1
                    puttCounter += 1
                }
                shotClub.strokesList.append(0)
            }

        }
    }
    func read() {
        NFCR.read()
    }
}
struct ReadNFCButton: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Spacer()
            HStack{
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "wave.3.left.circle")
                    .symbolRenderingMode(.monochrome)
                    .resizable()
                    .foregroundColor(.green)
                    .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fit)
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Observations: you have a number of `ObservableObject` classes, but you don't observe anything,
 that is, eg using `@Published var msg ...`. You should use `@StateObject var NFCR = NFCReader()` etc...
 Use the conventional practice of naming your var starting in lowercase, `nfcr` not `NFCR`.